# Training Tesseract for Captcha Recognition

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, captcha

Currently, Tesseract can read my captchas with around 25% accuracy only with --psm12 configuration.

I have gathered data and would like to train tesseract so that it can read my images with higher accuracy.

See raw image files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03v6C.jpg

See filtered image files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEozh.jpg

I cant seem to find any tutorials on how to train data from images? Also any suggestions on improving the image processing is welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

First I would try to remove the little dots and fill up gaps to remove interference. Take a look here how you could do that: [FillGapHowTo](https://github.com/cracker0dks/CaptchaSolver/blob/master/docs/howToSolve6DigitCaptchasWalkthrough.md#fill-gaps-and-reshape-it)

Second: OCR is likely to run better if you separate the letters: [could be done like this](https://github.com/cracker0dks/CaptchaSolver/blob/master/docs/howToSolve4DigitCaptchasWalkthrough.md#image-segementation)

Third: If nothing is working, you can use neuronal networks for the really hard captchas: [Here](https://github.com/cracker0dks/CaptchaSolver/blob/master/docs/howToSolveNew6DigitCaptchasWalkthrough.md#next-level-and-my-solution-train-a-neuronal-network)